# move vectors to specified coordinate

Tags: vector, qgis, coordinate-transformation

I have a layer of vectors located around, say, (100, 100), and I want to move them to new coordinate like (1000, 1000). How should I do it? Preferably using QGIS

Answer (score 1):

If using QGIS

- Get the **qgsAffine** plugin through the Plugin Installer.

  - make sure the QGIS Contributed Repository http://pyqgis.org/repo/contributed is connected.
- Select the features on the layer you want to edit and make the layer editable
- strat the plugin: Plugins > Geoprocessing > Affine
- Select the layer in the drop-down box and enter your desired translations in the unit of the currently used CRS

Comment: How do these translations work? Their homepage explain nothing!